# string and char elements

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have an `unsigned char* c` that contains the element 0x1c. How can I add it into an `std::vector<unsigned char>vect`? I am working in c++.

```
std::vector<unsigned char>vect;  //the vect dimention is dynamic

std::string at="0x1c";
c=(unsigned char*)(at.c_str());
vect[1]=c //error? why?
```

Comment: I'd say the error is because vect[1] is an unsigned char while c is a pointer to one. Maybe `vect[1] = *c`? I haven't used C++ in a while though.

Comment: Note: You probably want `vect[0]` rather than `vect[1]` if you want to set the first value.  Also, what error are you actually getting?

Comment: it i leave vect[0]=c i have the following error:  error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char’

Comment: if i put vect[0]=*c ..i have segmentation faul

Comment: @key Because you're trying to set the value of the first element, but you haven't made any elements yet. I recommend getting yourself a good C++ book; the basics of containers will be covered in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
//The vect dimension is dynamic ONLY if you call push_back
std::vector <std::string> vect;  

std::string at="0x1c";
vect.push_back(at);
```

If you are using C++, use std::string. The above code will copy your "0x1c" string into the vector.

If you try to do

```
vect[0] = c;
```

Without first expanding the vector with

```
vect.resize(1);
```

You will get segmentation fault because operator[] doesn't expand the the vector dynamically. The initial size of a vector is 0 btw.

UPDATE: According to the OP's comment, here is what he would want: copying a unsigned char * to a std::vector (i.e.copying a C array to a C++ vector)

```
std::string at = "0x1c";
unsigned char * c = (unsigned char*)(at.c_str());
int string_size = at.size();

std::vector <unsigned char> vect;

// Option 1: Resize the vector before hand and then copy
vect.resize(string_size);
std::copy(c, c+string_size, vect.begin());

// Option 2: You can also do assign
vect.assign(c, c+string_size);
```

Comment: i need to use std::vector<unsigned char> vect;

Comment: that code makes no sense.. why would you cast the `const char*` returned by `c_str()` to an `unsigned char*` and then call non existent method `pushback` with that? I don't believe there is a ctor of `std::string` which takes an `unsigned char*`!

Comment: I guess the point is that the OP has not really made what he wants clear, what you're doing above is basically going to insert 4 entries in to the vector, where each character's value will be inserted into the vector - i.e. `[ '0', 'x', '1', 'c']`. The OP has not said whether he wants this or a single entry in the vector with the value `0x1c`.

Comment: @Nim: I agree. I just give a solution based on my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hex representation of a character in a string, and you want the character?

easiest:

```
unsigned char c;
istringstream str(at);
str >> hex >> c; // force the stream to read in as hex
vect.push_back(c);
```

(I think that should work, have not tested it)

---

I just reread your question again, this line:

> I have an unsigned char* c that
>   contains the element 0x1c

Does this mean that actually your unsigned char* looks like this:

```
unsigned char c[] = {0x1c}; // i.e. contains 1 byte at position 0 with the value 0x1c?
```

or my assumption above...

---

to print the vector out to `cout`, use a simple for loop, or if you are feeling brave

```
std::cout << std::ios_base::hex;

std::copy(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(std::cout, " "));

std::cout << std::endl;
```

this will print the hex representations of each of the `unsigned char` values in the vector separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

c is an `unsigned char*`.  vect is a `std::vector<unsigned char>`, so it contains unsigned char values.  The assignment will fail, as `operator []` on `std::vector<unsigned char>` expects an `unsigned char`, not a `unsigned char *`.